# img and span with same svg render at different sizes in IE9

Tags: html, css, svg, internet-explorer-9

Our web app uses svg for a lot of its images.  Sometimes we put them in spans as background images, other times we put them in img tags.  The problem is, if we have the same svg used in both ways on the same page at different sizes, IE9 fails to resize the 2nd set of images.

An example is worth 1000 words:

test.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head><title>Foo</title></head>

  <style>
            .half { width: 16px; height: 16px; }
            .full { width: 32px; height: 32px; }  
            .double{ width: 64px; height: 64px; }

            span.img {
              display: inline-block;
              background-image: url('circle.svg');
              background-size: 100% 100%;
            }             
  </style>

  <body>            

    <b>Span</b><br />
    16: <span class="img half"></span>
    32: <span class="img full"></span>   
    64: <span class="img double"></span>
    <hr />

    <b>Img</b><br />
    16:<img src="circle.svg" class="half" />
    32:<img src="circle.svg" class="full" />   
    64:<img src="circle.svg" class="double" />
    <hr />

  </body>
</html>
```

circle.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" enable-background="new 0 0 32 32" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
  <circle r="16" cx="16" cy="16" />
</g>
</svg>
```

In Chrome and Firefox, it looks great. In IE9, the bottom images are all rendered at 32px, and cropped to fit the container.  If you remove either the spans or the images, all is fine and dandy.

Also, if you change the image url for either of them to 'circle.svg?' to get around browser cache, it also works fine.

Does anyone know any work arounds to this? How can I display both span and img tags with the same SVG content at the same time? The prospect of either changing all img tags to spans (or vice versa) is daunting, as is adding a fake query parameter to each one to get around cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `width="32px" height="32px"` from the SVG element will fix this